Cannot enable classes in Apex Class Access Permission Set
I've created four new Apex classes, two of them being test classes.  I want to 'enable' them in the Apex Class Access permission set.  I see them in the list on the left side of all the available classes, but when I select one or more of my classes and click on the right arrow to move the class to the 'enabled' side, nothing happens.  Does anyone know why that would be?  Thanks.

Idea - try in Classic

What license is associated with the permission set?

Adding in Classic worked!  Thanks.
